# How to create a looping animation that changes different background colors infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to achieve the following animation:

I have eight circles, four small and four large. The first one (small circle) has green background color, the rest of the small circles have gray background color, the large circles have red background color. The animation will, with each second that goes by, add green background color to the circles one at a time. When all the circles have background color green, then there will be a 1 second delay before the whole animation starts from scratch. The animation will repeat the animation infinitely.

TLDR: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/2LL5gz9r/1/)

*Initial state:* 1 small circle colored green, 3 small circles gray, 4 large circles red.

*In between:* one at a time, color each circle green every 1 second, until all the circles are green.

*Final state:* 4 small and 4 large circles colored green. Reset the initial state and repeat the animation infinitely.

-- EDIT START --

To those interested in the collective solution I put together, you may find it in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/2LL5gz9r/), it involves both CSS and jQuery. When you first see it, it will be using jQuery; to see pure CSS implementation, delete the comment in the CSS which will enable the animation markup. Make sure to comment jQuery out.

-- EDIT END --

Note: I would preferably like to find a **CSS only solution** but I am very novice regarding CSS animations and it's been a real pain so far, that is why I came here to ask for help. However if it is not possible using CSS alone, then please entertain a jQuery solution. In light of that, here is what I have tried in jQuery but to no avail:

HTML

```
<div class="smallCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="largeCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.smallCircles { 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallCircles .circle { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;    
}
.largeCircles .circle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    border-radius: 75px;
}
.smallCircles :first-child {
    background-color: green;
}
.smallCircles :not(:first-child)
    background-color: gray;
}
.largeCircles .circle { 
    background-color: red;
}
.bg--green {
    background-color: green;
}

.bg--gray {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var elements = [jQuery(".smallCircles :nth-child(1)"),
                    jQuery(".smallCircles :nth-child(2)"),
                    jQuery(".smallCircles :nth-child(3)"),
                    jQuery(".smallCircles :nth-child(4)"),
                    jQuery(".largeCircles :nth-child(1)"),
                    jQuery(".largeCircles :nth-child(2)"),
                    jQuery(".largeCircles :nth-child(3)"),
                    jQuery(".largeCircles :nth-child(4)")
                   ];
    var count = elements.length;
    var i;
    var infinitely = 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999;

    for(i = 0; i < infinitely; i++){
        try {
            if (i % count === 0) {
                resetColors((i % count), elements);
            }
            else {
                colorEach((i % count), elements);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    function resetColors (i, elements) {
        if (i > 0) { // the changes in here will have occurred on the second loop
            var timer;
            setTimeout(elements.each(function(index, element){
                if(index > 0 && index < 4) { // omit the first element in the list    
                    element.removeClass("bg--green");
                    if(index < 4) { // only the small circles
                        element.addClass("bg--gray");
                    }
                    if(index > 3) { // only the large circles
                        element.addClass("bg--red");
                    }
                }
            }), 3000);
        }
    }

    function colorEach (i, elements)  {
        switch (i) {
            // Small Circles, except the first one
            case 1:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 1);
            case 3:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 1);
                break;
            // Large Circles
            case 4:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 0);
                break;
            case 5:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 0);
                break;
            case 7:
                colorBackground(i, elements, 0);
                break;
        }
    }

    function colorBackground (i, elements, type) {
        if(type) { // type 1: large circle
            var timer;
            setTimeout(function(i, a){
                console.log("timeout function at colorBackground i: " + i);
                a[i].removeClass("bg--red");
                a[i].addClass("bg--green");
            }, 3000);
        }
        else { // type 0: small circle
            var timer;
            setTimeout(function(i, elements){
                console.log("timeout function at colorBackground i: " + i);
                elements[i].removeClass("bg--gray");
                elements[i].addClass("bg--green");
            }, 3000);
        }
    }
}
```

My failed attempts in CSS animations, this is 100% without jQuery:

```
.smallCircle :nth-child(2) {
    animation: smallCircle-2 1s infinite;
}
.smallCircle :nth-child(3) {
    animation: smallCircle-3 2s infinite;
}
.largeCircle :nth-child(4) {
    animation: smallCircle-1 3s infinite;
}
.largeCircle :nth-child(1) {
    animation: largeCircle-2 4s infinite;
}
.largeCircle :nth-child(2) {
    animation: largeCircle-3 5s infinite;
}
.largeCircle :nth-child(3) {
    animation: largeCircle-4 6s infinite;
}
.smallCircle :nth-child(4) {
    animation: largeCircle-4 7s infinite;
}
@keyframes smallCircle-2 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes smallCircle-3 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes smallCircle-4 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes largeCircle-1 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes largeCircle-2 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes largeCircle-3 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
@keyframes largeCircle-4 {
    99% { background:gray }
    100% {background:green;}
}
```

Comment: Is there a need to have this work in browsers that don't support CSS keyframe animation? Can you show us what you've tried using CSS-only?

Comment: _"4 large circles red."_ Where set to red at `css` ?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks I forgot to mark that change in my code
-daniel0mullins what I have basically done has failed utterly because I do not have a solid grasp of what animations to use to achieve this. I can post what I have tried right now, 1 minute please.

Comment: Why don't you use css animation? You just have to divide 100% into the number of steps your animation is keyframed and use those numbers for animating each

Comment: @Vandervals that's what I am trying to achieve however I really am having a hard time grasping how css animations work, which is the #1 reason why I came here to ask for help. Any help is 100% appreciated :) Also my code represents a small example of what I am trying to achieve potentially, so this is a big building block for me.

Comment: but I mean that you don't need jQuery at all. Why don't you put an easier user case, that could make you understand it easily and then you can apply your knowledge to any case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with CSS only, if a little tedious. You'll need to set up a new keyframes animation for each and every circle. Each circle stays gray and then turns green 12.5% (100 divided by 8) further into the animation than the previous animation. All animations are set to last 8 seconds and repeat ad inifinium.

The example code below uses the standard syntax. You may wish to add vendor prefixes to ensure legacy support, but all major browsers [currently support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) this syntax.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr6kdpfm/)

```
@keyframes a1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a2 {
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a3 {
    25% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a4 {
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a5 {
    50% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a6 {
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a7 {
    75% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes a8 {
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
}

.circle {
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: steps(1,end)
}

.smallCircles .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-name: a1;
}

.smallCircles .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-name: a2;
}

.smallCircles .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-name: a3;
}

.smallCircles .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-name: a4;
}

.largeCircles .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-name: a5;
}

.largeCircles .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-name: a6;
}

.largeCircles .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-name: a7;
}

.largeCircles .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation-name: a8;
}
```

Comment: I can totally learn from this on the CSS side of things, thanks man I really appreciate it!

Comment: @AGE i tried to do something clever with delays and durations to cut down on the code repetition, but there doesn't yet seem to be a way to force a delay on each iteration of the animation (only on the first iteration).

Comment: does your snippet include cross browser support, or should I assume it does not?

Comment: This code isn't cross browser compatible, you're going to have to add the appropriate vendor prefixes.

Comment: @AGE all major browsers currently support this syntax. you may wish to add vendor prefixes for legacy support. also, i've updated my answer with a slightly new technique that's cleaner and less computationally expensive on the rendering engine.

Comment: i didn't include vendor prefixes in my example because the code would be absurdly long (a different keyframes definition for each browser!) and because in a couple of years no one will remember what a vendor prefix was.

Comment: @Woodrow Barlow thanks for clarifying. I may have to suck it up and deal with these vendor prefixes for now due to the (annoying) older systems that I am dealing with. Hopefully those couple of  years will go by quick, do you have a reference to point to these vendor prefixes I need to look into?

Comment: As per my previous comment, @Jordan included in his reply the 'browser' supported version of Woodrow's solution, which is very neat and very appreciated. I could argue Jordan to modify Woodrow's answer instead, will let him know.

Comment: @AGE It's important to add browser support, I would definitely consider using an alternative like I included at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `.queue()`

```js
(function cycle(elems) {
  elems.queue("bg", $.map(elems, function(el, i) {
      return function(next) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          el.style.backgroundColor = "green";
          next();
        }, 1000)
      }
    })).dequeue("bg").promise("bg")
    .then(function(_elems) {
    console.log(_elems);
      setTimeout(function() {
        elems
        .slice(0, 1).css("backgroundColor", "green")
        .addBack()
        .slice(1, 4)
        .css("backgroundColor", "gray")
        .addBack()
        .slice(4)
        .css("backgroundColor", "red");
        cycle(_elems);
      }, 3000);
    });
}($(".circle")));
```

```css
.smallCircles {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallCircles .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.largeCircles .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 75px;
  background-color: red;
}
.smallCircles .circle:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
.largeCircles .circle {
  background-color: red;
}
.smallCircles .circle:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: gray;
}
.bg--green {
  background-color: green;
}
.bg--gray {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="smallCircles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="largeCircles">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AGE See updated post. Corrected color reset to initial for `.circle` elements after completion of `cycle`.

Comment: I noticed :) I actually adapted this to my personal implementation. The nice thing about the snipped I provided is that is highly customizable and your solution keeps the doors open to that.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
This effect can be achieved entirely with CSS keyframes and animation.

**Browser support I've included:**
Firefox 5+, IE 10+, Chrome, Safari 4+, Opera 12+

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rf90ew42/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="smallCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="largeCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.smallCircles { 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallCircles .circle { 
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
.largeCircles .circle {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.circle {
    -webkit-animation: 8s infinite;
    -moz-animation: 8s infinite;
    -o-animation: 8s infinite;
    animation: 8s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    -o-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
}

.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state1;
    -moz-animation-name: state1;
    -o-animation-name: state1;
    animation-name: state1;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state2;
    -moz-animation-name: state2;
    -o-animation-name: state2;
    animation-name: state2;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state3;
    -moz-animation-name: state3;
    -o-animation-name: state3;
    animation-name: state3;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state4;
    -moz-animation-name: state4;
    -o-animation-name: state4;
    animation-name: state4;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state5;
    -moz-animation-name: state5;
    -o-animation-name: state5;
    animation-name: state5;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state6;
    -moz-animation-name: state6;
    -o-animation-name: state6;
    animation-name: state6;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state7;
    -moz-animation-name: state7;
    -o-animation-name: state7;
    animation-name: state7;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state8;
    -moz-animation-name: state8;
    -o-animation-name: state8;
    animation-name: state8;
}

@-webkit-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% {background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
```

```css
.smallCircles { 
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.smallCircles .circle { 
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
.largeCircles .circle {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.circle {
    -webkit-animation: 8s infinite;
    -moz-animation: 8s infinite;
    -o-animation: 8s infinite;
    animation: 8s infinite;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    -moz-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    -o-animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
    animation-timing-function: steps(1,end);
}

.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state1;
    -moz-animation-name: state1;
    -o-animation-name: state1;
    animation-name: state1;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state2;
    -moz-animation-name: state2;
    -o-animation-name: state2;
    animation-name: state2;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state3;
    -moz-animation-name: state3;
    -o-animation-name: state3;
    animation-name: state3;
}
.smallCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state4;
    -moz-animation-name: state4;
    -o-animation-name: state4;
    animation-name: state4;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state5;
    -moz-animation-name: state5;
    -o-animation-name: state5;
    animation-name: state5;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state6;
    -moz-animation-name: state6;
    -o-animation-name: state6;
    animation-name: state6;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(3) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state7;
    -moz-animation-name: state7;
    -o-animation-name: state7;
    animation-name: state7;
}
.largeCircles > .circle:nth-of-type(4) {
    -webkit-animation-name: state8;
    -moz-animation-name: state8;
    -o-animation-name: state8;
    animation-name: state8;
}

@-webkit-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% {background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state1 {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state2 {
    12% { background-color: gray; }
    12.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state3 {
    24.5% { background-color: gray; }
    25% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state4 {
    37% { background-color: gray; }
    37.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state5 {
    49.5% { background-color: gray; }
    50% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state6 {
    62% { background-color: gray; }
    62.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state7 {
    74.5% { background-color: gray; }
    75% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-moz-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@-o-keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
@keyframes state8 {
    87% { background-color: gray; }
    87.5% { background-color: green; }
    100% { background-color: green; }
}
```

```html
<div class="smallCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="largeCircles">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**Alternative:**
Due to browser compatabilty the code can get very repetitive, since we're using the same declarations, but with different vendor prefixes. A nicer way of doing this would be using a CSS preprocessor, such as **[LESS](http://lesscss.org)**. This would cut the code down dramatically, example below.

**LESS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes some-animation {.state1;}
@-moz-keyframes some-animation {.state1;}
@-o-keyframes some-animation {.state1;}
@keyframes some-animation {.state1;}

.state1 () {
    0% { background-color: green; }
    100% {background-color: green; }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing mate, I am regrettably stuck on working with these browser compatibility issues due to the client's we're servicing, but you did great in providing this solution. I would argue to modify the accepted answer's solution to include these changes, would make more sense in the long run. Either ways your help is 100% appreciated! (going to try to sneak LESS in for sure into my code).

Comment: Yes LESS is a far better approach to achieve this, and will certainly leave your coding looking more clean. This is the proper way of doing the transition you wanted using regular CSS. So even if Woodrow hadn't answered your question, my answer would have remained the same way. He's says that " in a couple of years no one will remember what a vendor prefix was." but we live in the present, things should be done properly so that every get's the same experience, even on older browsers.

Comment: No problem mate. If my answer has helped, please consider marking it as the accepted answer, as this will ensure people viewing this question has the full solution to this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: The truth is that even though your answer is correct it is also an expansion from Woodrow's answer (not that you copy pasted him, but it is an expansion in the general sense of the word). The fact is that your answer is more helpful but at the same time I cannot disregard Woodrow's work. That is why I have up voted your answer as well as suggested you to edit Woodrow's answer based on your conclusions, which in turn would be more relevant to those viewing the question.

Comment: No problem, what are you needing this code for if you don't mind me asking? What's the project?

Comment: it's a simple animation for a larger site, the are various animations like the one in my example occurring in a loop. My problem was lack of knowledge in CSS regarding animations. I thought I could do it in jQuery (and nearly did) but my solution was a mess compared to @guest271314. I always aim to ask questions in a general manner as to help others implement them in their own way, so circles seemed simple enough for anyone to help & base their solutions from. From there I can apply it to any shape I want :)